# Azure MySQL transaction.atomic() in Django gives a server error

Tags: mysql, django, azure

I use an Azure VM, mysqlclient==1.4.6, Django==2.1.5

My code in admin.py:

```
from django.db import transaction
...
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
...
```

settings.py:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': DB_HOST,
    'PORT': '3306',
    'NAME': 'db',
    'USER': ...,
    'PASSWORD': ...,
    'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'ssl': {'ssl-ca': '...'} # i modified it
    }
```

I get:

***The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.***

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you share full error message? Internal server error means that status 500 was raised, but this can happens because variety of reasons

Comment: how can I find this message on Azure? This is a production server.

Comment: If you're not running the project now on production, I guess the simplest way is to set `DEBUG=True` in your settings - this will display exception trace on the page.

Comment: i use logging, but for admin.py I get nothing

Comment: Is exception message captured to your logger? It's not obvious because you showed only upper part of `try` block.

Comment: yes, I add it to logger, but there is no exception. Right now I am trying to see the server error.